# Read lines from one file and write to another file but remove lines that contain certain string

Tags: python, line

I'm trying to read a text from a text file, read lines, delete lines that contain specific string (in this case 'bad' and 'naughty').
The code I wrote goes like this:

```
infile = file('./oldfile.txt')

newopen = open('./newfile.txt', 'w')
for line in infile :

    if 'bad' in line:
        line = line.replace('.' , '')
    if 'naughty' in line:
        line = line.replace('.', '')
    else:
        newopen.write(line)

newopen.close()
```

I wrote like this but it doesn't work out.

One thing important is, if the content of the text was like this:

```
good baby
bad boy
good boy
normal boy
```

I don't want the output to have empty lines.
so not like:

```
good baby

good boy
normal boy
```

but like this:

```
good baby
good boy
normal boy
```

What should I edit from my code on the above?

Comment: Why are you replacing dots with spaces in lines you want to ignore anyway?

Comment: @Wooble Maybe OP expects that to be a regular expression, where he would `replace` all occurrences of `anything` in `line` with `nothing`.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can make your code simpler and more readable like this

```
bad_words = ['bad', 'naughty']

with open('oldfile.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

using a [Context Manager](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typecontextmanager.html) and [any](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any).

Answer (score 9):

You could simply not include the line into the new file instead of doing replace.

```
for line in infile :
     if 'bad' not in line and 'naughty' not in line:
            newopen.write(line)
```

Comment: i think you want "or" instead of "and"

Comment: i want the lines that only contains one of bad or naghuty to be deleted too. which one is right..?

Comment: @H.Choi It's either `not ('bad' in line or 'naughty' in line)` or `not 'bad' in line and not 'naughty' in line`, so `and` here should be correct.

Answer (score 7):

I have used this to remove unwanted words from text files:

```
bad_words = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']

with open('List of words.txt') as badfile, open('Clean list of words.txt', 'w') as cleanfile:
    for line in badfile:
        clean = True
        for word in bad_words:
            if word in line:
                clean = False
        if clean == True:
            cleanfile.write(line)
```

Or to do the same for all files in a directory:

```
import os

bad_words = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = True):
    for file in files:
        if '.txt' in file:
            with open(file) as filename, open('clean '+file, 'w') as cleanfile:
                for line in filename:
                    clean = True
                    for word in bad_words:
                        if word in line:
                            clean = False
                    if clean == True:
                        cleanfile.write(line)
```

I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to do it, but this did what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3):

Today I needed to accomplish a similar task so I wrote up a gist to accomplish the task based on some research I did. 
I hope that someone will find this useful!

```
import os

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

oldfile = raw_input('{*} Enter the file (with extension) you would like to strip domains from: ')
newfile = raw_input('{*} Enter the name of the file (with extension) you would like me to save: ')

emailDomains = ['windstream.net', 'mail.com', 'google.com', 'web.de', 'email', 'yandex.ru', 'ymail', 'mail.eu', 'mail.bg', 'comcast.net', 'yahoo', 'Yahoo', 'gmail', 'Gmail', 'GMAIL', 'hotmail', 'comcast', 'bellsouth.net', 'verizon.net', 'att.net', 'roadrunner.com', 'charter.net', 'mail.ru', '@live', 'icloud', '@aol', 'facebook', 'outlook', 'myspace', 'rocketmail']

print "\n[*] This script will remove records that contain the following strings: \n\n", emailDomains

raw_input("\n[!] Press any key to start...\n")

linecounter = 0

with open(oldfile) as oFile, open(newfile, 'w') as nFile:
    for line in oFile:
        if not any(domain in line for domain in emailDomains):
            nFile.write(line)
            linecounter = linecounter + 1
            print '[*] - {%s} Writing verified record to %s ---{ %s' % (linecounter, newfile, line)

print '[*] === COMPLETE === [*]'
print '[*] %s was saved' % newfile
print '[*] There are %s records in your saved file.' % linecounter
```

Link to Gist: [emailStripper.py](https://gist.github.com/Azlirn/a7107212401f1865106a5e1476303f3e)

Best,
Az

Answer (score 3):

Use python-textops package :

```
from textops import *

'oldfile.txt' | cat() | grepv('bad') | tofile('newfile.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `else` is only connected to the last `if`. You want `elif`:

```
if 'bad' in line:
    pass
elif 'naughty' in line:
    pass
else:
    newopen.write(line)
```

Also note that I removed the line substitution, as you don't write those lines anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this works well.

```
import re

text = "this is bad!"
text = re.sub(r"(.*?)bad(.*?)$|\n", "", text)
text = re.sub(r"(.*?)naughty(.*?)$|\n", "", text)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a little quicker than the accepted answer (for my 23 MB test file) that I used. But there isn't a lot in it.

```py
import re

bad_words = ['bad', 'naughty']

regex = f"^.*(:{'|'.join(bad_words)}).*\n"
subst = ""

with open('oldfile.txt') as oldfile:
    lines = oldfile.read()

result = re.sub(regex, subst, lines, re.MULTILINE) 

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    newfile.write(result)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you [include code and output as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4162689), please?

Comment: @JamesGeddes, thanks.  I've never thought this was an issue before now. I've read the link and it makes sense.  In this case, I've posted my code as text as well but I guess it would be better to show the output results as text too.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_skip = ("bad", "naughty")
out_handle = open("testout", "w")

with open("testin", "r") as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if set(line.split(" ")).intersection(to_skip):
            continue
        out_handle.write(line)
out_handle.close()
```

Comment: Won't work if there's something like `this is bad!` in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

```
bad_words = ['doc:', 'strickland:','\n']

with open('linetest.txt') as oldfile, open('linetestnew.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

The `\n` is a Unicode escape sequence for a newline.