# Removing pattern matched line from multiline string in python

Tags: python

I have a multiline text string, that looks like:

```
AAAA BBBBBB
BBBB VVVV XXXX

CCCCCCCC XXXX
```

I'd like to come up with a small function that removes an entire line if it contains a word/phrase , so that for above if I lets say sent in 'VVV' as a paremeter the output would be:

```
AAAA BBBBBB

CCCCCCCC XXXX
```

There are many examples on stackoverflow, eg [Remove lines that contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968998/remove-lines-that-contain-certain-string), which show how to do this for a file, but I'm not sure how without opening a file.

Comment: OK, so where is your code ? and whats the problem with it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string
'AAAA BBBBBB\nBBBB VVVV XXXX\n\nCCCCCCCC XXXX'
>>> re.sub(".*VVV.*\n?","",my_string)
'AAAA BBBBBB\n\nCCCCCCCC XXXX'
```

you can define a function and can do for any substring:

```
>>> def remove(rem,my_string):
...     return re.sub(".*"+rem+".*\n?","",my_string)
... 
>>> remove("VVV",my_string)
'AAAA BBBBBB\n\nCCCCCCCC XXXX'
>>> remove("XXX",my_string)
'AAAA BBBBBB\n\n'
>>> remove("BBB",my_string)
'\nCCCCCCCC XXXX'
>>> remove("CCCC",my_string)
'AAAA BBBBBB\nBBBB VVVV XXXX\n\n'
```

Comment: I'll accept it , although I prefer using string functions over regex if possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> text = '''AAAA BBBBBB
BBBB VVVV XXXX

CCCCCCCC XXXX'''
>>> text = '\n'.join(line for line in text.split('\n') if 'VVV' not in line)
>>> print text
AAAA BBBBBB

CCCCCCCC XXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = "AAAA BBBBBB\nBBBB VVVV XXXX\n\nCCCCCCCC XXXX"

ans = ""
pattern = "VVVV"
for line in inp.split("\n"):

    if line.find(pattern)<0:
        ans=ans + line+"\n"
print ans
```

Comment: Python doesn't have `!`, you can use `not` instead