# how to delete all lines containing Letters and characters for a textfile

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a textfile containing words, numbers, and characters. I want to delete all lines with the characters and words, and keep the lines with numbers.
I found out that all those lines with words and characters have the letter of "r". so I wrote my code as:

The textfile contains these lines as an example:

```
-- for example
-- 7 Febraury 2022
5 7 1 5 3.0 2
3*2 3 5 7.0 3
```

and I want to keep these 2 lines:

```
5 7 1 5 3.0 2
3*2 3 5 7.0 3
```

This is the code written:
textfile = open('test.txt', 'r')
A = textfile.readlines()

```
L = []
for index,name in enumerate(A):
    if 'r' in name:
        L.append(index)

for idx in sorted(L, reverse = True):
    del A[idx]
```

I know it is not a good way to do that, is there any suggestion to do that?

Comment: Same question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968998/remove-lines-that-contain-certain-string

Comment: Hi, one possible solution could be using regular expressions using the python "re" module. For each line in the file you could search for a \w+. If true, skip that line.

Comment: You need to provide sample input and expected output

Comment: sure, I updated that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find only the words using `regex`

```
import re
with open(r'text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

with open(r'text_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in data:
        if re.findall(r"(?!^\d+$)^.+$", line):
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I didn't know about regex. Can we exclude some letters or characters from that? For example, if there is an * in the lines, it keeps the line but for other characters, it deletes the lines?

Comment: of course! you can add what you want to the regex, if you need help doing this just say ;) @PeymanBahrami

Comment: Actually yes, I need a little bit help on this. I am reading the documents about regex. it says to negate a character or letter use hyphen. but I dont understand where to use that. in the same line?

Comment: you need to use it in the regex. I recommend you to look at this site - https://regexr.com/ to try some regex.  if you need more help, tell me the problem

Comment: I updated the question for more details. sure, thank you very much. I think I need to read more about it.

Comment: This Regex is so complex. your code now returns an empty list. I searched your code:
(?!...) Negative lookahead assertion
(^$ ) finds the patterns
I dont understand when they are in combination

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without importing anything (e.g., re) then you could do this:

```
keep_these = []

def is_valid(t):
    try:
        float(t.replace('*', '0'))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return False

with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if all(is_valid(t) for t in line.strip().split()):
            keep_these.append(line)

print(keep_these)
```

Thus the *keep_these* list will contain references to the lines you want to keep which you could, for example, use to re-write the file

Comment: thank you for your reply. in my textfile there are some lines having both numbers and words. I want to delete them as well. The problem with this code is that it keeps those lines.

Comment: That is **NOT** what you asked for in your question. I quote: "I want to delete all lines with the characters and words, and keep the lines with numbers"

Comment: Thank you Olvin, your code works very well on my example. If you dont get mad at me, may I ask your help for another part. my text file is so big. so I couldnt bring it here. In some lines I have the numbers like 3.0. your code could not exclude such a format and considers the line to be deleted.

Comment: Answer edited to allow for new information about the input/output requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex library `re`. One way to do that is to loop through the lines and then keep the line only if `re.match("[^0-9 ]", line) == None`.